# "unknown: this object doesn't support multiple channels" during encryption

Tags: encryption, pipeline, encryption-symmetric, crypto++

I am getting *"unknown: this object doesn't support multiple channels"* exception during file encryption. I am able to generate session key but it can not be used to encrypt file.

The following is my code snippet for file encryption:

```cpp
void enc_file_EAX(PAES_KEY_WITH_IV key, const char *in_file, const char *out_file)
{

    try {
        CryptoPP::EAX<CryptoPP::AES>::Encryption encryptor;
        encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key->key, key->key.size(), key->iv);
        CryptoPP::FileSource f(in_file, true,
                     new CryptoPP::AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,
                        new CryptoPP::FileSink(
                             std::string(in_file).c_str()),
                             CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |
                             CryptoPP::AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END ));
        std::fstream file(out_file, std::ios::binary | std::ios::ate);
        size_t remaining = file.tellg();
        file.close();
        size_t BLOCK_SIZE = 16384;
        while (remaining && !f.SourceExhausted()) {
            const unsigned int req = std::min(remaining, BLOCK_SIZE);
            f.Pump(req);
            f.Flush(false);
            remaining -= req;
        }

    } catch (const CryptoPP::Exception& e) {
        std::cout << e.GetWhat() << std::endl;
        return;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me on this ? What is going wrong here ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key->key, key->key.size(), key->iv);
FileSource f(in_file, true,
        new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,
            new FileSink(
                std::string(in_file).c_str()),
            AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::THROW_EXCEPTION |
            AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter::MAC_AT_END ));
```

You are mixing and matching encryption and decryption gear in the same object pipeline. You should probably fix that first.

Looking at [AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter), the `THROW_EXCEPTION | MAC_AT_END` flags  are probably being coerced into the `putAAD` flag:

```
AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher &c,
    BufferedTransformation *attachment = NULL, bool putAAD=false,
    int truncatedDigestSize=-1, const std::string &macChannel=DEFAULT_CHANNEL,
    BlockPaddingScheme padding=DEFAULT_PADDING);
```

I seem to recall you need to avoid the [Pipelines](http://cryptopp.com/wiki/Pipelining) if you want to add AAD. The pipe only allows inputting data on `DEFAULT_CHANNEL`, which provides AE (but no AAD). Also see [EAX Mode | AEAD example](https://cryptopp.com/wiki/Eax_mode#AEAD) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

Your use of `FileSink` and `FileSource` does not quite look right. I'm not sure how this is going to behave:

```
FileSource f(in_file, true, ...
    new FileSink(std::string(in_file).c_str()), ...);
```

You should probably use `in_file.c_str()` for the file name:

```
FileSource f(in_file.c_str(), ...);
```

You should also probably use a different file for the sink:

```
FileSource f(out_file.c_str(), ...);
```

---

***EDIT*** (from the comments):

> No , we don't want to add pipeline, we just want to use DEFAULT_CHANNEL for inputting data. And given example is for text input. I want to use same function for file inputting. Can you elaborate more on this?

In this case, try:

```
EAX<AES>::Encryption encryptor;
encryptor.SetKeyWithIV(key->key, key->key.size(), key->iv);
FileSource f(in_file.c_str(), true,
        new AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter(encryptor,
            new FileSink(out_file.c_str()));
```

That should input text for confidentiality and integrity (AE). It will avoid text with confidentiality only (AEAD).

Also see [EAX Mode](http://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/EAX_Mode) on the Crypto++ wiki. It has three or four examples with both AE and AEAD.

Comment: No , we don't want to add pipeline, we just want to use DEFAULT_CHANNEL for inputting data. And given example is for text input. I want to use same function for file inputting. Can you elaborate more on this?

Comment: Thanks, only one thing is wrong in your answer is that I need not call c_str() function as in_file and out_file has char * data type. Rest all things are good. Thank you again.